# Kubernetes state of the pod when running preStop command

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using preStop command to gracefully shutdown my server application when I delete a pod. What is the state of the pod/ container when it runs preStop command? For example, does it stop the network interfaces before running the preStop command?

```
lifecycle:
    preStop:
      exec:                
        command: ["kill", "-SIGTERM", "`pidof java`"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The state of the pod doesn't change while preStop hooks are run -- the preStop hook is run in the container, and then the container is stopped.

Answer (score 2):

When a pod should be terminated, Kubernetes does the following:

1. Switch the Pod to the `Terminating` state
2. Invoke the `preStop` hook (if any)
3. Once the `preStop` hook ends, it sends a `SIGTERM` to the main process in the container (PID 1)
4. If the container doesn't terminate with the termination grace period (30 seconds by default - starts counting at point #1), Kubernetes will send a `SIGKILL` to the container's main process to violently stop it

More details here:
[Graceful shutdown of Kubernetes Pods](https://pracucci.com/graceful-shutdown-of-kubernetes-pods.html)